# Element don't aligned

Tags: html, css

I place this form into div that is class container and I wonder why labels are aligned next to the input field horizontal. What i should add in css file?

```
  <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Please include your CSS, and preferably an image of what you have and what outcome you're looking for, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a flexbox for the `form-group` is an option. Is this layout what you need?

```css
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40%;
}

.form-group:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you have a label with a class of `-sm-2` and one of `-sm-10` and both have a display of `inline`.

you need to add in your css:

```
.control-label, .form-group div {
    display: block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try this:*

```
.form-group {
  display: table-row;
}

.col-sm-10 ,label {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```css
.form-group {
  display: table-row;
}

.col-sm-10 ,label {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> 
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```